# How to convert python response in string to Json

Tags: python, response

I am trying to return a json response, but all i get is str type response

```
import json
import requests
def Execute(query):
        try:
        response = requests.post(API_URL, headers=HEADERS,json={'query': query})
        response = json.loads(response)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response,200 
        else:
            return response,400             
    except Exception as e:
        return e, 500
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the body of your response before pass it to `json.loads`, just change the line:

```py
response = json.loads(response)
```

To:

```py
response = json.loads(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly get the `json` object using the following:

```
response = requests.post(API_URL, headers=HEADERS,json={'query': query})
response_json = response.json()
```

You don't need to use `json.loads()`.

Comment: so i need to return response_json , 200 right?

Comment: after saving the above code, i try to open my python3 shell and created a post action and got that in response , and did print(response.read()) all i get is a <class 'str'> output, could you please help on that.

Comment: you need `response.json()` and not `read()`

Comment: this is what i get when i try to print(response.json()) 
""AttributeError: 'Post' object has no attribute 'json' ""

Comment: have you removed this line `response = json.loads(response)` from the code?

Comment: Yes i removed that line , this is how my code looks now '    try:
        response = requests.post(API_URL, headers=HEADERS,json={'query': query})
        response_json = response.json()
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response_json,200 
        else:
            return response_json,400             
    except Exception as e:
        return e, 500'

Comment: not sure what's wrong, do you get `200` as status code? and can you try to print the response before calling json method?

Comment: didn't get your point, by json method you mean before response_json = response.json()?

Comment: I meant just print the response.text and status code to see if you get a valid response

Comment: yes i am getting proper response when i print response.text without json parsing

Comment: ok, what if you use `json.loads(response.text)`?

Comment: same error "AttributeError: 'Post' object has no attribute 'json'"