# Python - Requests module "response.text"

Tags: python, python-requests

How do I get a specific element from requests response.text

```
{"status":"success","data":{"id":30815925}}
```

im need to get ID from that output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert python response in string to Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66118657/how-to-convert-python-response-in-string-to-json)

Answer (score 0):

You can import the json package and simply do

```
import json

id = json.loads(response.text)["data"]["id"]
```

This will convert `response.text` from a string to a python dictionary, and the id will be inside the variable `id`

Comment: it gives me error: id = response.text["data"]["id"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: This means that response.text is a string and you need to convert it to a dictionary using json package